# Convey time lag information to a linear regression model

Tags: linear-regression, forecasting, forecast

I am using a simple linear regression to predict the **number of units an item has moved** and **price of the item** is one of the input parameters.

For a few items, the older prices are not relevant and hence this results in incorrect predictions. The definition of `old price` varies from item to item. 
Is there a way to make the linear regression know that recent prices are more relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear regressions have fixed number of variables. An alternative could be to run a separate regression for each item group, and add a different number of time lags for each. If you can't do that, I suggest you to find an optimal number of time lags to be chosen for this general model. You can take a look at **ACF**, and specifically **PACF** plots to understand how much memory (time dependency) your time series have.

In theory, adding a more time lags should't result in a problem: if the n-th time lag is not relevant to explain your *y*, then it's parameter will show no statistical significance.

Comment: Thanks for answering. "An alternative could be to run a separate regression for each item group, and add a different number of time lags for each"- how do I do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the nature of your data and your specific task. I wrote it in case it was possible to do that, but I don't know it it's the case. If you can't / it's not feasible, then go for the analysis of (P)ACF plots for time dependency, and find an optimal number of time lags for your regression model.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.

Comment: If you find it useful, please consider accepting my answer and/or upvoting :)

Answer (score 0):

The predictions are bad because the weight is too high for the "old price" feature (variable/column) of your dataset.
If the coefficients are not well adjusted, the problem comes from the **training** rather than the dataset.

Here is what you can do:

1. Find out the **coefficient** (weight) for each feature. In sklearn, there is a property called .coef_ for [LinearRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).
2. If you find the coefficients are *too high*, you can try **[Ridge regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html#sklearn.linear_model.Ridge)** to penalize high coefficients.
3. Otherwise, if you want to *reduce the coefficient* of less important variables to a minimum, try **[Lasso regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html#sklearn.linear_model.Lasso)** with several values for alpha (ex: 0.5,0.1,0.01)